# ajax error xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Tags: php

i have a error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null test:29
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange". when using ajax.

my code in php like this :
whats wrong with my code ?

```
<select name="data" onchange="showUser(this.value)" class="form-combobox">                                        
<?php  
$qrySelect = mysql_query("select * from m_motor");   
echo'<option>-Choice Data-</option>';                              
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($qrySelect)){
  echo "<option value=$data[code_motor]>$data[code_motor]</option>";
}
?>
</select> 
<div id="txtHint"><b>-Choice Data-</b></div>
```

and in javascript code like this:
whats wrong with my code here ?
please help me...

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
  if (str=="")   
{
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("data").value =xmlhttp.data;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getAjax.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: it is because your select tag should have an id ="data" and not name="data" as you have written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace this as your **first code snippet**.

```
    <select id="data" onchange="showUser(this.value)" class="form-combobox">                                        
    <?php  
    $qrySelect = mysql_query("select * from m_motor");   
    echo'<option>-Choice Data-</option>';                              
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($qrySelect)){
      echo "<option value=$data[code_motor]>$data[code_motor]</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select> 
    <div id="txtHint"><b>-Choice Data-</b></div>
```

Also, i don't think there is a xmlhttp.data attribute. If you need to pass multiple values using ajax, try json encoding.

Comment: not working  sir :(... u can send link to this solution ? thanks.